# Problem getting value from a clicked-button, back to flask

Tags: python, html, ubuntu, flask, button

I have multiple buttons, for a mobil platform tool. created from a dynamic list, using flask and python3.8. I can not seem to get the value from the button itself (a filename, to be used by the function call to start a specific script on the pi server.) The list itself is created fresh based on what files are in a specific directory, the web portal just creates a button for each file, in a clickable format. The desired result is after the click, html passes the filename back to python as a variable, to be executed by a function call.. I am fairly new to programming like this, so this is likely a simple thing for most of you, but I have been trying everything I can and can't get it to work, and google, in this particular case, is not my friend ;)

the x is a value from the list of files in the source dirtectory. all of this works as it should.if i set a static file name I can even start the file.

---

file.html

```
    <h1>Available Menu</h1>
    <p>###### #######</p>
    <ol>{% for x in lr1 %}
    <div class="flex-parent jc-center">
    <a href='/run'><input type='button' onclick="/make" name="Selection" value="{{x[2:-4]}}"></a>
    <a href='/make'><input type='button' onclick="/make" name="Selection" value="{{x[2:-4]}}"></a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    <p>  Please make your selection by clicking on it.</p>
```

---

I have gone through many differnt attempts at forms, sessions, etc... , but this is where I am right now. the first href if just for testing purposes, for site flow. The second one is the one I will be using for actual operations.

---

file.py

@app.route('/make', methods=['get', 'post'])

def makefile():

```
#  make/run selected file. 
sel_name = ''   #   needed input variable
###    missing piece...
cmdgg = '/##########.sh /media/rbins/{}'.format({sel_name})     # script call
print(cmdgg)
subprocess.Popen(cmdgg, shell=True).wait()
print(f'######')    #   confirmation message
```

---

i have tried so many variations now, and none seem to cut it so I am not going to even complete this function, because I must be approaching it incorrectly. I have everything else working, i am only missing this one component...  I am even open to just creating a text file in the root dir that I can parse to make the command, but again, I cant make that work either.. This is an area I still need to learn a bit more on.

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: these are just snippets, there is a lot more code, but this is the only area I need help with...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid more confusion id suggest you to check out flask_wtf is used to creating forms and its exactly what you need in order to send data from client to back-end. Happy coding !

Comment: It turned out I had a small misunderstanding about the values within the button statement.. Thats why I wasn't able to make it work all the other ways I tried. Once I realized what I had wrong, one of the very first soutions I tried worked.... Thanks for the recommendations though, I learned more new things along the way. :)